# Issue building Expo project to generate AAB file "Unable to resolve module ./src/aws-exports"

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, react-native, expo

I'm facing an issue when trying to generate an Android App Bundle (AAB) file for my Expo project. Internally, I can run the project without any problems, but when attempting to create the distribution package, the build process fails with the following error message:

```
> Task :app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets
[stderr] 
Error: Unable to resolve module ./src/aws-exports from /home/expo/workingdir/build/App.js: 
[stderr] 
None of these files exist:
[stderr] 
  * src/aws-exports(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.cjs|.native.cjs|.cjs)
[stderr] 
  21 | import {Amplify} from '@aws-amplify/core';
[stderr] 
  22 | import {Storage} from '@aws-amplify/storage';
[stderr] 
> 23 | import awsconfig from './src/aws-exports';
[stderr] 
     |                        ^
[stderr] 
  24 | Amplify.configure(awsconfig);
[stderr] 
  25 |
[stderr] 
  26 | const PlaceholderImage = require('./assets/images/upload-image.png');
[stderr] 
Error: Unable to resolve module ./src/aws-exports from /home/expo/workingdir/build/App.js: 
[stderr]
```

This is happening when attempting to build the AAB file using the Expo CLI. As mentioned, the project works correctly when run locally, but building the AAB is encountering this issue.

Comment: Try deleting your node_modules folder and your package-lock.json (or yarn.lock if you’re using Yarn), then run npm install (or yarn install) again.

Comment: It's work here, thanks!!